# Can you have private URLs in Amazon's CloudFront?

Tags: cloud-computing, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

In Amazon's S3 storage system you can have sort of private URLs using a special query string and expiring the link after a while.

Is such a private system possible using Amazon's CloudFront, which is based on S3?

Answer (score 3):

You can now serve private content from CloudFront.

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=3514&categoryID=216